# What will happen if i implement stack with top=0 in array implementation

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

I have implemented stacks using top=-1, everything is fine. But, what will happen if i make it 0. Can i implement using it? and in queue implementation, rear is at -1, front is at 0 initially, what will happen if rear is at 0?

Comment: How do you mean top=-1? Usually top points at the top of the stack. If you use an array and point at 0 in the beginning you will just point at an empty/uninitialized place. It might help to show us some code to have an example. Actually there are a lot of ways to implement a stack depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Top is chosen to be -1 , because in general implementation it is incremented when the push function is called. But this is not a mandatory rule.

The only thing you have to remember is that it always points to the topmost element or the last added element, no matter how you implement it. I hope that makes sense.

Same with the front/rear variables in queue implementation.

Comment: In stack, i have implemented at top=0, but my lecturer told that there is a problem in implementing queue with rear and front at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can do anything that you want!
How do you mean top=-1? Usually top points at the top of the stack. If you use an array and point at 0 inexample